# .hasClass not working inside a onclick function but remove and add class functions do

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#vDets').on('mouseover',function(){
             $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectHov");

 });
$('#vDets').on('mouseout',function(){
             $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectHov").addClass("SelectDef");
 });
 $("#vDets").on('click',function(){              
            $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectTick");
             var boolCheck = $("#vDets").hasClass("SelectDef");


 });
});
```

I am having trouble with the code above, hasClass works when not inside the onclick function but throws an error

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hasClass is not a function

when used inside despite the fact that the functions removeClass and addClass both work.

i have used hasClass many times before and never encountered this issue

Comment: Would you please create jsfiddle for this, then I can try it out there

Comment: Is `#CurrentPageId` div exists?

Comment: what is `CurrentPageId`? you are adding `SelectDef` class to `vDets` but checking on `CurrentPageId`...

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please make a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org) that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/phihag/xb2jst8c/). Can you post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Malik, Ryxle: It is irrelevant whether the specific ID exists, `$().hasClass` (on an empty jQuery object) is still a function.

Comment: I disagree. to use `hasClass` you need to have an HTML element inside the jQuery object.

Comment: @Ryxle, nope, to use function from jQuery, you just need jQuery object, nothing more

Comment: you can test it with empty jQuery object and jQuery object with HTML element. Please observe objects in console log in your web browser...

Comment: @Ryxle, you also can check it `$().hasClass()` - and get _false_ instead _Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hasClass is not a function_

Comment: here what you are doing is accessing methods in jQuery. When you pass a selector to jQuery it tries to find the element and if not found jQuery create a null jQuery object. that's why you see two different outputs...

Comment: #CurrentPageId was only in there as a mistake as i was testing out another div in the page to see if the error is still thrown, i have edited my question with the correct div id, as stated above, it doesnt matter what div id is checked as it should still be classed as a function and return true or false

Comment: Check whether it conflicts with any other js included in the same page.

Comment: @Ryxle, you wrong, jQuery **never** create **null**, only **empty object**

Comment: sorry! my bad empty object...

Comment: I have jsut created a fiddle with the same code and it seems to work correctly with no issues, it seems there is something in the page that i am using which is causing the conflict, Thanks for the help on this issue, seems to be conflicting with something just not sure what it is yet

Comment: :D I also created one and trying to figure out what happened. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXwVjK?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tested it, everything seems fine on 
[jsfiddle - click.](https://jsfiddle.net/wvss577s/6/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#vDets').on('mouseover',function(){
             $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectHov");

 });
$('#vDets').on('mouseout',function(){
             $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectHov").addClass("SelectDef");
 });
 $("#vDets").on('click',function(){              
            $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectTick");
            //those run after click
            var boolCheck1 = $("#vDets").hasClass("SelectDef");
            var boolCheck2 = $("#vDets").hasClass("SelectHov");
                        $('#result1').text( boolCheck1 );
            $('#result2').text( boolCheck2 );
 });
 //run outside function without click
 $('#result1').text( $("#vDets").hasClass("SelectDef") );
 $('#result2').text( $("#vDets").hasClass("SelectHov") );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vDets" class="SelectDef">
click me
</div>
result for SelectDef:
<div id="result1">

</div>
result for SelectHov:
<div id="result2">

</div>
```

Maybe are you trying to use `boolCheck` outside function? It's not avalible outside :)

EDIT: And you cant remove class here:

```
 $("#vDets").on('click',function(){              
            $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectTick");
```

Cause when u wanna click it will be `SelectHov`:

```
$('#vDets').on('mouseover',function(){
             $('#vDets').removeClass("SelectDef").addClass("SelectHov");

 });
```

Comment: thanks, i figured out the issue i had a conflict in the page, not sure where from but have add noConflict to this section of code and it is now working, i have however updated the on click section to remove the removeClass and instead just toggle the tick class on and off instead.